# searchDisplayController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Here my code:  Need to remove my warning . i am under iOS 9

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if (searchText.length>0) {

        self.searchBarActive = YES;



[self filterContentForSearchText:searchText scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                                   objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }else{
        // if text lenght == 0
        // we will consider the searchbar is not active
        self.searchBarActive = NO;
    }



}
```

Need to remove my warning as i mention in my question.It should work with above iOS 7. I am new to ios. But need to remove my warning message .I have tried below code:

```
if([UISearchController class]){
//Create an UISearchController and add it to your UITableViewController
}else{
//Create an UISearchDisplayController and add it to your UITableViewController 
}
```

But seriously i don't know how to implement that .If any one help me with code explanation will be helpful me to know for further move.Thanks @@

Comment: If your Deployment Target is iOS 7 then you wouldn't get this deprecation warning and you can safely keep using `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: No i need for iOS 9 also bro. So only its needed for me to remove this warning

Comment: Do you want to support iOS 7? If so, remove the warning (and support iOS 7) by setting your Deployment Target to iOS 7.

Comment: OK if I need it for iOS 7 Above means or only for iOS 9..?? I am doing project that should work for iOS 9 bro. So only its need to remove my warning

Comment: OK then. You wish to support iOS 7, 8, and 9. So, for the third time now. Set your Deployment Target to iOS 7.0. The warning will go away. You can use `UISearchDisplayController`. It will work just fine under all three versions of iOS.

Comment: and my co workers are need to run also in iOS 9 deployment target . So if i change the Deployment target means,while run in xcode -deployment ios 9 it will show warning know. so only i need to clear this warning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94228/discussion-between-2131-and-rmaddy).

Comment: @rmaddy Please suggest some thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.h

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;`

.m

```
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchText scope:[[self.searchController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
```

this coding working well....