# Search bar not showing in full-width in landscape orientation for above ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I recently followed one git hub project for Collection view search bar.In that there is a search bar, collection view cell .All working well in potrait mode. When i use landscape mode to see, the screen search bar alone showing half -width size.Here is the search bar code .I use programatically to add search bar.

**NOTE:**  **I am using deployment target 7.0 should run in all version of ios 7,8,9 devices.**

**How to make my search bar with same width & height with full width in landscape mode.**

My code:

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
@interface CollectionViewController ()<UISearchBarDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray        *dataSource;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray        *dataSourceForSearchResult;
    @property (nonatomic)        BOOL           searchBarActive;
    @property (nonatomic)        float          searchBarBoundsY;

    @property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar        *searchBar;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) UIRefreshControl   *refreshControl;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // datasource used when user search in collectionView
    self.dataSourceForSearchResult = [NSArray new];

    // normal datasource
    self.dataSource =@[@"Modesto",@"Rebecka",@"Andria",@"Sergio"];

}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self prepareUI];
}
-(void)dealloc{
    // remove Our KVO observer
    [self removeObservers];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - actions
-(void)refreashControlAction{
    [self cancelSearching];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // stop refreshing after 2 seconds
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}


#pragma mark - <UICollectionViewDataSource>
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.searchBarActive) {
        return self.dataSourceForSearchResult.count;
    }
    return self.dataSource.count;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    if (self.searchBarActive) {
        cell.laName.text = self.dataSourceForSearchResult[indexPath.row];
    }else{
        cell.laName.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -  <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.searchBar.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat cellLeg = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2) - 5;
    return CGSizeMake(cellLeg,cellLeg);;
}


#pragma mark - search
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.dataSourceForSearchResult  = [self.dataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    // user did type something, check our datasource for text that looks the same
    if (searchText.length>0) {
        // search and reload data source
        self.searchBarActive = YES;
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchText
                                   scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                          objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                         selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }else{
        // if text lenght == 0
        // we will consider the searchbar is not active
        self.searchBarActive = NO;
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self cancelSearching];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.searchBarActive = YES;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    // we used here to set self.searchBarActive = YES
    // but we'll not do that any more... it made problems
    // it's better to set self.searchBarActive = YES when user typed something
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    // this method is being called when search btn in the keyboard tapped
    // we set searchBarActive = NO
    // but no need to reloadCollectionView
    self.searchBarActive = NO;
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
-(void)cancelSearching{
    self.searchBarActive = NO;
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.searchBar.text  = @"";
}
#pragma mark - prepareVC
-(void)prepareUI{
    [self addSearchBar];
    [self addRefreshControl];
}
-(void)addSearchBar{
    if (!self.searchBar) {
        self.searchBarBoundsY = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.searchBarBoundsY, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
        self.searchBar.searchBarStyle       = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
        self.searchBar.tintColor            = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.searchBar.barTintColor         = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.searchBar.delegate             = self;
        self.searchBar.placeholder          = @"search here";

        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // add KVO observer.. so we will be informed when user scroll colllectionView
        [self addObservers];
    }

    if (![self.searchBar isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
        [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    }
}

-(void)addRefreshControl{
    if (!self.refreshControl) {
        self.refreshControl                  = [UIRefreshControl new];
        self.refreshControl.tintColor        = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                                action:@selector(refreashControlAction)
                      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    if (![self.refreshControl isDescendantOfView:self.collectionView]) {
        [self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
    }
}
-(void)startRefreshControl{
    if (!self.refreshControl.refreshing) {
        [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    }
}

#pragma mark - observer 
- (void)addObservers{
    [self.collectionView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
- (void)removeObservers{
    [self.collectionView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" context:Nil];
}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(UICollectionView *)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"] && object == self.collectionView ) {
        self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                          self.searchBarBoundsY + ((-1* object.contentOffset.y)-self.searchBarBoundsY),
                                          self.searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                          self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Also Get full project here [Git-hub](https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar)

Here the portrait mode image:

[image]

This same search bar when i run in landscape my sea[image]rch bar is in half with like this:

What code i need to add to set my search bar with full-width view in landscape mode.Thnaks!

Comment: How do you feel about using constraints?  That would solve it without writing any code using the size class.

Comment: s bro.But i dont know about adding programatically constraint for search bar.. now thats a problem. i have tried to add but it throw me error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following when your view loads or appears:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
   object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Then add the following method in your View Controller :

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
 CGRect frame = _searchBar.frame;
frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
_searchBar.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: i added with your code in `case  case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:`But  no my search bar has fill the space in landscape

Comment: actually my deployment target i have set as 7.0. So now which one should i use to achieve my search bar to look in full in landscape mode for all versio ios7,8,9

Comment: Ok will search some other solution for your problem then

Comment: please use my git hub link to  see add any constraint or does i need to change the width value in some where.i too tried buy i am not able to get

Comment: Updated Answer and now its working fine in your Github project

Comment: i have one question........If i set my deployment target as 7.0-- Then if i run my app in device which run in ios 7 , 8 , 9  does my app will work well..

Comment: Not for deployment target bro.

Comment: my app is fully deployment as 7.0..does it will work in all devices which run in ios 7,8,9

Comment: Yes it will !! Just remember to remove observer on either viewDidUnload or viewWillDisappear.

Comment: please look at this post one of my co worker having probem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529452/warning-about-sendsynchronousrequestreturningresponseerror-is-deprecatedfirs

Comment: and also this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527619/searchdisplaycontroller-is-deprecated-first-deprecated-in-ios-8-0

Comment: bro please help to slove that problem in that 2 link i have sended.They working deployment as 9.0

Comment: Working on SearchController question only bro.

Comment: yes ,thats also warning about to use searchdisplaycontroller

Answer (score 4):

I have used your project in github. Lets make the changes to work full search bar in landscape mode: Replace the below code as it as in your `addsearchbar` method :

```
-(void)addSearchBar{
    if (!self.searchBar) {
        self.searchBarBoundsY = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.searchBarBoundsY, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
        self.searchBar.searchBarStyle       = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
        self.searchBar.tintColor            = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.searchBar.barTintColor         = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.searchBar.delegate             = self;
        self.searchBar.placeholder          = @"search here";


     // added line-to set your screen fit and autoresizing with width and bottom margin.You can also add any position to that

        [self.searchBar sizeToFit];

        _searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // add KVO observer.. so we will be informed when user scroll colllectionView
        [self addObservers];
    }

    if (![self.searchBar isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
        [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    }
}
```

Hope this help !